# Display a post under the form after submitting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build something similar to Facebook's posting system.

Goal: Display a new DIV below an INPUT TEXT field upon the user clicking POST. The DIV should display the contents of the text field.

This is what I have tried:

#### HTML

```
<div class="update">
    <p>Update </p>
    <div class="feed-me" ></div>
    <input type="text" name="update status" Id="cmm_box" placeholder ="What's on your mind " />
    <input type="button" value="post"/>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```
<script >
    var text front = "" ;
    var text end = " @user name " ;

    $(document).ready ( function ) {
        $('input  [ type=button] ' ).click(
            function ( ) { update( ); }
            );
        });

    function update( ) {
        $( ' div.feed_me ' ) .html ( textfront + $ ( ' cmm_box ' ).val( ) + textend ) ;

        $( ' div.feed_me ' ) .html ( textfront + $ ( ' cmm_box ' ).val( ) + textend ) ;

        $( ' div.feed_me ' ) .html ( textfront + $ ( ' input [ name=update ] ' ).val( ) + textend ) ;

</script >
```

Comment: I assume `<input type="text" name="update status" I'd="cmm_box" ...` should actually be `<input type="text" name="update status" id="cmm_box" ...`

Comment: Do you have PHP and database interactions as well?

Comment: assuming it should be `id="cmm_box"`, then all you attempts using `$ ( ' cmm_box ' )` should include a `#` (for `id` selector) -> `$ ( ' #cmm_box ' )`

Comment: I am a big fan of a bit of white space in code to make it readable, _but there are limits_ Specifically the limit is when a space actually destroys the syntax of the language your are mangling